# php cookie unset + setting cookie to a garbage value followed by js redirect not working to log user out, why?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to log a user out in the event that I suspect a csrf attack (tokens not matching). I'm testing this out when I hit the following else condition:

```
else
{
            session_destroy();
            unset($_COOKIE['email']);
            unset($_COOKIE['userhash']);
            unset($_COOKIE['name']);

           $crapname = makeTokenCookie("crap", $con);
            setcookie('user', 'garbage', time()+rand(1,100), NULL);
            setcookie('name', 'garbage', time()+rand(1,100), NULL);
            setcookie('userhash', 'garbage', time()+rand(1,100), NULL);
            setcookie('id', 'garbage', time()+60*60*24*30*6, '/', NULL);
            setcookie('email', 'garbage', time()+60*60*24*30*6, '/', NULL);

            alertMe("Your session has timed out. Please login again.");
            echo "<script>document.location.href='index2.php'</script>";
            exit();
}
```

I let users auto-log in with cookies which is why I explicitly unset them here. Yet when the user is redirected to index2.php, she's logged in already via cookie. I use these same lines of code when the user presses the logout button, and that works fine. Any idea why the following code is not unsetting the cookie to something?

Comment: Why are you storing an email address inside a cookie? Also, why 5! cookies?

Comment: @Jack, I'm learning so if you have other suggestions, I'd welcome them. For my site, email address is user name. Then I use userhash so people can't manipulate their cookies to get access to other people's account via cookie login. Finally I access id and name and user(type of user) properties all the time so I thought I'd store them in a cookie rather than retrieve them for a session variable. Also my understanding is local storage is not a permanent thing but only by session, maybe I am wrong. These are smallish text fragments, is this really too much for cookies?

Comment: This is exactly what you should just use sessions for; only one cookie to keep track off

Comment: @Jack but if you use just one cookie that cookie value can be stolen. At least with a pair of cookies you can cross check them against each other so, which is even better than just 1 long hash. Don't want people fiddling with the values to guess those of other people right? What is the downside of my 5 cookie setup?

Comment: If one cookie can be "stolen", the same can apply to five of them so that's not an argument for having more cookies. Session hijacking is a studied subject so I would suggest looking into countermeasures if you're worried about it.

Comment: @Jack It's not about stealing so much as stealing and manipulating. If you have a pair that should match, it's much harder for someone to use their own cookies or stolen cookies to hijack someone else's account. I'm still not clear on what's bad about 5 cookies?

Comment: You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist; manipulating a session cookie by changing its value is like finding a needle in a rather large haystack. Also, session cookies don't disclose personal information such as email address.

Answer (score 0):

`unset()` doesn't remove cookies. You need to create a cookie with the same name that expires in the past to have it actually be removed. You are also creating the cookies with a future expires date after you try to unset them which is counter productive.

```
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
setcookie(session_name(), '', strtotime('-1 year'));
setcookie('user', '', strtotime('-1 year'));
setcookie('name', '', strtotime('-1 year'));
setcookie('userhash', '', strtotime('-1 year'));
setcookie('id', '', strtotime('-1 year'));
setcookie('email', '', strtotime('-1 year'));

alertMe("Your session has timed out. Please login again.");
echo "<script>document.location.href='index2.php'</script>";
exit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I came to this system because Mozilla does not unset cookies or delete them even after their expiration date. That's why I unset the cookies and then fill them with garbage. It usually works for me.

Comment: AFAIK this isn't a known bug in FF so it may have to do with how you handle cookies in your code.

Comment: Obviously you know more than I, but setting cookies to times in the past has never worked for me on Firefox. And I am not the only one at least as of last January 2014: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/983361

Comment: That's specific to a user having too many cookies. It's not caused by any code you or I could write.

Comment: Well I guess I have that problem even though I usually clear my cache every day. In any case, if a user could have that problem, seems like security wise I should assume they do have that problem no? Otherwise they haven't really logged out right?

Comment: It's an odd problem to assume. If we couldn't assume cookies would be deleted when we wanted to it would break lots of apps. And I wouldn't use cookies (other than a session cookie) to handle authentication. More secure and solves your problem.

Comment: hmmm, but it seems like all the big sites certainly do use cookies - otherwise how come I don't need to log into anything other than my bank account?

Comment: and I agree it's an odd problem to assume. I lost an entire day on this when I was first adding cookies to my site before finally (all too slowly) figuring out that my mozilla was not deleting cookies no matter how far in the past I set their expiration date. So at least to me this does not seem like an esoteric problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69936/discussion-between-beeb-and-john-conde).